# how do i lock down my preferences for Services .mmc snapin column layout and view type

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, service, settings

when "Services" opens, it's in Extended View.

I prefer Standard view.

I also prefer this column layout:

```
    Status  | Startup Type  |  Log On As  | Name | Description
```

because when I expand all columns via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+(numeric keypad) <kbd>+</kbd>
what I need to see most I can view without being forced to scroll
to the right.

Problem:  my preferred layout does not persist.

QUESTION:  how can I force Windows (2008 R2, 7, XP, et cetera) to remmember my settings?

Answer (score 1):

The answer for XP and 2003 is here: https://superuser.com/questions/50130/how-can-i-open-winxps-services-control-panel-applet-on-the-standard-tab-by-defau

I can't, however, seem to get that working with Win7 / 2k8 server. Must be a wrinkle I haven't stumbled over yet.

Comment: still does not work with my win7 but it does work with win8.1; perhaps it has skipped a generation.  **B-(**

Answer (score 1):

On Win7 a partial solution is to use the technique mentioned by Chris_K. And then use *File* > *Save As* and save it as a new `.msc` file. It won't integrate with Windows but can be used from command line / <kbd>Win+R</kbd> prompt.